# Format JSON String (bson)

Tags: java, bson

I use the bson Document class to create json strings (and for mongodb).

But the json string isn't fancy. All is in one line.
How can I format the json string to an fancy (multiline) json string?

Answer (score 1):

Ultradiv's answer is great in regard to viewing JSON within a browser, however I am not sure if your question is also asking about printing JSON within your console as your run your application.

If so, I like to use [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson). I am making this suggestion based on your java tag. If you would like to make it pretty, you could do something as follows:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
String json = gson.toJson(obj);
System.out.println(json);
```

If you would like some more information, take a look at the following guides:

[How to convert Java object to / from JSON (Gson)](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/)

[How to enable pretty print JSON output (Gson)](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-enable-pretty-print-json-output-gson/)

Comment: I would like something like a single class which I can add to my project, not an full API :/

Comment: D: I understand, maybe you could only import the Maven dependency and instantiate an object of GSON class? I am using it in my projects and doesn't take up more than a few lines of code. Any other alternatives I have discovered have not been too helpful. If I find any links I can post them here.

Comment: Nope, if I add Maven dependency it export the full api into the target jar :/

Answer (score 0):

I use a simple Chrome plugin to view validated JSON in a pretty way
[here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-formatter/bcjindcccaagfpapjjmafapmmgkkhgoa?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog)

however there are online JSON beautifiers out there my fav being [this](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

is it worth re-inventing the wheel by building one yourself? not from my point of view